# My SqlDataReader Has No Rows?

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, sqlclient

When I'am debugging my console says that my reader has no rows.
Below you can find the code.

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {
        bool isSucces = false;


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-9DG53HK\TOMSQL;Initial Catalog=Webshop;Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();

            string username = loginViewModel._username;
            string password = HashPassword(loginViewModel._username, loginViewModel._password);


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Username = @Username and Password = @Password;", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);


            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    int Role = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Role"]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
            }

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            bool loginSuccessful = ((ds.Tables.Count > 0) && (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0));


            if (loginSuccessful)
            {
                //return View(new LoginViewModel(isSucces, Role));                       
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid username or password");
            }

        }
        return View();
    }
```

The program skips the while loop completely. I have been searching for a while but could not find the answer maybe you guys see what is wrong.

Comment: you sure you are sending right parameters for `username` and `password`? can you put a breakpoint and confirm that you have right values and your select does return data? also, shouldn't your query put username and password as quoted string? `SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Username = '@Username' and Password =  '@Password';`

Comment: are you that the query returns the actual result in the DB?

Comment: @Veljko89 username and password are having the correct values.

Comment: @Veljko89 I also tried the quoted string. Didn't work..

Comment: @Veljko89 quoting parameters converts them to *text*. Parameters *ensure* that you never need quoting. If you need to use quoting, it means you are using string concatenation and are susceptible to SQL injection

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for clarification

Comment: @Bogatom you are reading all rows and *discarding* them in the loop. There's nothing left to put into the dataset after that. Remove the loop entirely.

Comment: @Bogatom BTW delete all that code and never use it again - storing cleartext passwords just *begs* for a data breach. MVC **already** supports authentication with strong password hashing *and* role authorization using SQL server. There's no reason to write your own code. If you show that code to an interview, you'd get an immediate `no hire`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos come on man, he is just learning and playing around ...

Comment: @Veljko89 and seat belts aren't needed when learning to drive right?

Comment: You are funny man :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, when you have used `SqlDataAdapter` why do you need `SqlDataReader`?
I recommend `SqlDataAdapter` because it also manages `Connection` and better approach then `SqlDataReader`. There are many things you must have to follow up with `SqlDataReader` which are `Reader.Close()`, `Reader.Dispose()`, `Connection.Open()` and `Connection.Close()` and `Reader` most likely fails on multiple hits when it is not async.

you can simply execute your code like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
int Role = 0;    
bool loginSuccessful = false;
if(ds != null && ds.tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
  Role = Convert.ToInt32(ds.tables[0].Rows[0]["Role"]);
  loginSuccessful = true;
}
else
{
  // No rows found
}
```

Secondly (asnwering your actual question):
      there must be no match with the passed parameters therefore `0` Rows.

Comment: he says dat the ds.tables[0].rows.count > 0 in the if statement 0 is?

Comment: @Bogatom the real question is why are you writing this insecure code instead of using MVC's authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive that you are receiving data from your SELECT query?
Try replacing it with a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = 1;
```

I would also replace your if reader.HasRows with a simple trycatch as more comprehensive error handling.